# use c++ unsigned int *array in c#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, arrays, dll

I have a c++ .dll exporting a function with the following signature:

```
extern int __stdcall foobar(long ptr, unsigned int *array, unsigned int arraySize);
```

From c++ Code, I can use it like so:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> FooBar(6);
int res = foobar(ptr, &FooBar[0], (unsigned int)FooBar.size());
```

I'd like to use the dll from C# and I've tried this:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
public static extern int foobar(long ptr, uint[] arr, uint arrSize);
```

Call:

```
uint[] arr = new uint[6];
int count = Obj.foobar(ptr, arr, (uint)arr.GetLength(0)*32)
```

This throws an "PInvokeStackImbalance" error. What would the correct PInvoke signature look like?

Comment: Have you tried `public static extern unsafe Int32 foobar(void* ptr, UInt32* array, UInt32 arraySize)` and performing the marshalling yourself?

Comment: That *ptr* is not long, it is `IntPtr`.  size is wrong too, it is `* 4`.  What it actually *means* is hard to guess at, raw pointers are usually trouble.

Comment: @Dai : Do you have an example for that? I would prefer going without unsafe code if that's possible...

Comment: @HansPassant ptr comes from a different function returning long: `extern long __stdcall createPtr(int val);`

Comment: The translation of C++ `long` to .NET is `System.Int32`.  Using C# `long`, which is `System.Int64`, will not work.  Also `std::vector`'s `size()` member returns the number of elements, not the number of bytes, so multiplying `GetLength(0) * 32` is wrong.  Not sure where 32 came from to begin with.  Just `(uint)arr.Length` will be correct there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to make use of the [MarshalAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute, for your array parameter.  This essentially describes to the marshalling system how to convert between the C# managed type and your raw C++ function parameter.

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
public static extern int foobar(
    IntPtr ptr, //Need more details on this parameter
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=2)] uint[] arr,
    uint arrSize);
```

Your "ptr" parameter is a bit confusing, since it's not mentioned in your question, but it's most likely just something you can treat as a regular old C++ pointer, in which case IntPtr is the appropriate type.

In the MarshalAs attribute, we are telling the marshalling system to convert your "uint array" into a raw, long-pointer-compatible C++ array.  The SizeParamIndex tells it to use the "arrSize" parameter, when allocating the array's size during conversion.